# Cannot transmit message (receiving is working, but without ack) on CAN bus (LPC2368)

Tags: can, lpc, arm7, lpcxpresso, lpc43xx

I work with microcontroller [LPC2368](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC2364_65_66_67_68.pdf).

After initialisation of the CAN interface to normal mode (not listen-only mode), I can receive all messages, but the microcontroller cannot send an acknowledge with the error code in register CAN1ICR->ERRBIT = 0X19 (Acknowledge slot).

In the same way, the microcontroller can't send a message on the CAN bus with error CAN1ICR->ERRBIT = 0x03 (Start of frame). Why can the microcontroller receive all messages, but have problems when writing on the line?

Comment: Very much a Baud rate mismatch issue!

Comment: Where do you receive CAN messages from?

Comment: The problem was in hardware

Comment: @Sauber I have the same problem of getting Start of Frame messages . How did you fix the issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006567/can-communication-between-lpc-2292-and-lpc1758-boards-start-of-frame-error

Comment: @Swanand How should i debug this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

> After initialisation of the CAN interface to normal mode (not listen-only mode), I can receive all messages, but the microcontroller cannot send an acknowledge with the error code in register CAN1ICR->ERRBIT = 0X19 (Acknowledge slot).

Referring the user manual, this error status is triggered as a result of errors occurring when other nodes on the bus dont ACK that they received a message successfully. This can be due to, variable baud rates among the nodes or simply using just 1 node on the bus and sending a message. Make sure all nodes are configured to have the same Baud rate and a minimum of 2 nodes are connected to the bus.

Additionally, to can also perform an  bus loopback using only 1 node by enabling Self Test Mode(no need of ACK to declare that a message has been sent successfully) and Self reception request(Reflect TX differential data into the Rx buffer) and check if the transmitted data is correct.

> In the same way, the microcontroller can't send a message on the CAN bus with error CAN1ICR->ERRBIT = 0x03 (Start of frame)

This can be checked by probing to see if the start of frame TTL Tx signal appears as a differential signal on the bus. Check the transceiver functionality as well.